# Change default of Illustrator rectangular grid tool?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, tools, grids

Is there any way I can change the default of rectangular grid tool to 1 by 1. It's at 5 by 5. I keep using the grid tool as guide so.

Answer (score 1):

Double click the **Grid Tool** and change the dividers:

[image]

Comment: I know how to use this but the default is 5 by 5 . i want to set it up to 1 by by